# Custom voice Recognition for an App in Android Wear

Tags: android, voice

Is it possible to set a custom voice recognition intent to execute a task(display a specified note) in android wear?

I have searched the following voice intent Doc https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html#FreeFormSpeech and it states only inbuilt voice intents.